# "No such file or directory" error when using "cat" in python

Tags: python, file, cat

When I use

```
cat folder1/folder2/*_in.txt>>output.txt
```

directly in the terminal, it works fine.

But when I call from inside the python process, it shows an error `"No such file or directory"`:

```
command = "cat "+path+"*_in.txt >> " + output_variable
print(command) # print exactly the same.
os.system(command) # error : cat: folder1/folder2/*_in.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `os.system` is definitely a shell

Comment: @Omer, that's untrue. `os.system(something)` calls `['sh', '-c', something]`. `sh` is very much a shell.

Comment: Right, deleted my misleading comment.

Comment: Why use `os.system()` instead of the Subprocess module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when there are no files matching the pattern:

```
$ python -c 'import os; os.system("cat *.txt")'
cat: '*.txt': No such file or directory

$ echo 'Hello World' > myfile.txt

$ python -c 'import os; os.system("cat *.txt")'
Hello World
```

Be aware that files are matched relative to the process's current working directory (`os.getcwd()`), and not relative to the Python file. If you can't figure out the working directory and correct relative path to your files, use absolute paths.

Comment: I changed the code to use the code suggested by the other user who deleted the post!, I mean in python itself using for loop and it works. But I have another command to run : "chmod +x "+filename and using os.command(), it gave me the same problem. I tried to use the absolute path. Notice that the file is in the same folder.

Comment: I prefer to know how it works using directly os.command, so I can use it in other commands.

Comment: I don't have an `os.command()` in my Python 3.7.6 and I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: sorry i meant os.system(). Between, plz ignore that I said about chmod, as I figured out the problem. But still, I can't run a command to concatenate all txt files.

Comment: Can you write a short, self-contained demo script that I will be able to run on my machine to see the problem? (i.e. a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).